# SharePoint 2013 Provision with SPMeta2 API ListModels

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In the code below, which is using the SPMeta2 API to provision SharePoint artifacts.

What are the `FieldModels`, `ContentTypeModels`, and `ListModels`?
I can't find a definition for them in the samples.

```
var siteModel = SPMeta2Model
               .NewSiteModel(site =>
               {
                   site
                       .WithFields(fields =>
                       {
                           fields
                           .AddField(FieldModels.Contact)
                           .AddField(FieldModels.Details);
                       })
                       .WithContentTypes(contentTypes =>
                       {
                           contentTypes
                           .AddContentType(ContentTypeModels.CustomItem)
                           .AddContentType(ContentTypeModels.CustomDocument);
                       });
               });

        using (var context = new ClientContext(targetSite))
        {
            var povisionService = new CSOMProvisionService();
            povisionService.DeployModel(SiteModelHost.FromClientContext(context), siteModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that sample from? Most likely, that's an old one. It shows how to use syntax API to build up a site model. FieldModels, ContentTypeModels here are static classes, they aren't included in the sample to cut the length of the sample.

It could be recommended to check out documentation here:
http://docs.subpointsolutions.com/spmeta2/

Basics here - you will get the idea of FieldModels, ContentTypeModels, etc: 
http://docs.subpointsolutions.com/spmeta2/basics/

Getting started and a simple console application here:
http://docs.subpointsolutions.com/spmeta2/basics/getting-started/

Also, there are some old samples at github, might be of use, not sure:
https://github.com/SubPointSolutions/spmeta2.contoso

Enjoy!